# Tkinter module cant be found

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

First time posting so please bear with me. I installed `PyCharm` and have interpreter 3.8.2, I tried

> import tkinter

but it returns

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

I also tried with Tkinter (despite it being for another version). I tried adding `future` to the project and running through

> from future.moves import tkinter

but that returns the same error as above. I also checked to make sure the path was right and can see that it looks fine. The autofill even recognizes that in the `future` library there is a folder named moves and tkinter. I also noticed a lot of answers on the boards describing that tkinter is included by default but from reading other posts it seems that for PyCharm that is not the case.
Can anyone offer any suggestions? Please also let me know if I have left out an important detail.

Comment: are you using python 3 ?

Comment: How did you install python? I have seen this before when people install python from the microsoft store instead of from python.org.

Comment: @Atlas435 yes 3.8.2 Novel I got the entire pycharm package from JetBrains

Comment: @Clippy I think pycharm is too advanced for you at the moment. I recommend you download python from python.org and use the editor that comes with it: IDLE. Check out learnpython.reddit.com for a beginner oriented python question forum.

Comment: What does it say when you run `import sys; print(sys.executable)`? Does it return the path for the Python 3.8.2?

Answer (score 0):

You should get `Python 3`, and run your code with `IDLE`. Install python [here.](https://www.python.org/downloads/) Then you should be able to use `tkinter`.